# spring mvc + spring aop + aspectj

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

I struggle to use aspect in Spring MVC project.

Method that is a pointcut is running fine, but without advise.

Here is class, that starts whole spring boot and that is root of spring context:

```
@Lazy
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@Configuration
public class MainSpringBootClass{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MainSpringBootClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is class with method, that is pointcut.

```
@Component
@Log
@Aspect
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class MyExampleClass
{
    public void example()
    {
        System.out.println("example");
    }
}
```

And here is my aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class MyAspect implements MethodBeforeAdvice
{
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.MyExampleClass.example())")
    public void asd()
    {
        // pointcut
    }

    @Before("asd()")
    public void login()
    {
        System.out.println("im am logging in");
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.example.MyExampleClass.example())")
    public void login2()
    {
        System.out.println("im am logging in2");
    }

    @Override
    public void before(Method method, Object[] args, Object target) throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("aop before");
    }
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
@RestController
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class MyExampleController
{
    private final MyExampleClass myExampleClass;

    @Inject
    public AdController(MyExampleClass myExampleClass)
    {
        this.myExampleClass = myExampleClass;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index()
    {
        myExampleClass.example();

        return "x";
    }
}
```

As You can see, I have been trying to bruteforce correct result with annotations.
I have also seen on some website, that I need specific dependencies, so here are mine (pasting only those, related to aspects):

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-aop:+'
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:+'
compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:+'
compile 'cglib:cglib:+'
compile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:+'
```

All dependencies have been successfully downloaded, project compiles and runs fine.
When I hit localhost:8080 then I see returned value "x", and inside logs I see "example".
However, I do not see any advices from spring aop nor aspectj - what am I doing wrong?

I am just using this project as sandbox to learn aspects, so I would be eager to learn, how to do it with each of Spring AOP and AspectJ.
The most important thing for me is to do it all without XML.

EDIT:
I have added simple constructor to MyAspect with println to check, if it is created (as it is normal spring bean with @Component after all) and it does - it is correctly created by spring.

EDIT 2:
IntelliJ IDEA tells me about methods login and login2: "This advice advices no method", but at the same time, I am able to jump (with control-click) from string, that is value in annotations to correct implementations.

Comment: Something to try would be to make sure your pointcut syntax isn't missing something. e.g. what if you try to broaden it like this: `@Before("execution(* com.example.MyExampleClass.*(..))")`

Comment: it is correct - IntelliJ IDEA let's me jump to correct method, when I control-click it.
I have also tried adding two dots and boarding range with * - still no expected output (but everything runs).

Comment: could be a dependency issue? you could try using http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop instead of http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop (initially you can try to simplify by taking out the aspectj references just to see if it works)

Comment: I have replaced dependency of AOP as You suggested - nothing changes.
Removing AspectJ dependency along @Aspect annotations also doesn't do anything.

Comment: You need `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` only one time on the `@Configuration` class, not on every class...

Comment: I have just tried to leave this annotation only on MainSpringBootClass and it does not change anything.

Comment: @xinus01 how do you get an instance of MyExampleClass? Are you getting it from the spring context or creating it with `new`

Comment: @Evgeni it is injected to MyExampleController by spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should need is something like this:

```html
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

    @Before("execution(* com.example.MyExampleClass.example(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("before...");
    }
}
```

You might have to replace all of the aspectJ dependencies with `spring-boot-starter-aop` .

Here's an example project that works (see `RestControllerAspect.java`):

**https://github.com/khoubyari/spring-boot-rest-example**

Comment: it's works for `@Before` advice... prints out the message and the controller completes it's task. https://github.com/khoubyari/spring-boot-rest-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/khoubyari/example/RestControllerAspect.java

Comment: I have tried to replace both login() methods to
public void login(JoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
it doesn't change anything.

Also, this pjp does not even have method proceed (but it has other methods).

I have also looked at this project and compared imports - I have very same.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought if you follow the spring-boot simple configuration of AOP (including the dependency management part) the way the above project does, you should be able to get the same results. In the project the pointcut is slightly different but that shouldn't be an issue. Also note the lack of any `EnableAspectJAutoProxy` anywhere.